# why is LogSeverity #defined as DWORD in windows SetupAPI

Tags: winapi, setupapi

I see this #define in windows kit 10 SetupAPI.h in line 4871

> #define LogSeverity                 DWORD

So I can't do something like

> typedef int LogSeverity

This effectively makes LogSeverity like a reserved keyword if I dont want to redefine DWORD. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hmm interesting, not sure,  maybe to support older environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows API has a huge number of such identifiers, what I actually find surprising about this case is that it's a #define and not a typedef. Although with it being a define it does give you the option of #undefing it after the include in question. Although I would likely just accept that it is an already used identifier and choose another name for whatever I was creating.

'Why' questions of this form generally don't have answers, only workarounds.

```
#include <setupapi.h>
#undef LogSeverity
```

Comment: Actually, the *"why"* is trivially simple: It's there to establish a stable ABI.